# Cannot mount a CIFS network share on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, windows-server-2008, ubuntu, vpn, network-share

I am trying to connect to Windows Server 2008 network share on Ubuntu, but for some reason it is not working.

I have the following entries in my `fstab`:

```
//server/foo    /mnt/foo    cifs    username=aron,password=foobar    0       0
//server/bar  /mnt/bar  cifs    username=aron,password=foobar    0       0
```

I get the following error after calling `mount -a`:

> mount error(110): Connection timed out
>   Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page
>   (e.g. man mount.cifs)

The output of `dmesg | tail` is:

```
[ 6697.441061] CIFS VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation
[ 6697.441078] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -110
```

I have no clue about why this command is timing out. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:** the OP explained this was only happening when trying to mount over a VPN connection, but it seems to happen with a physical connection as well.

Comment: What type of VPN are you using?  What do you get when you try to do a traceroute to the server you are trying to mount?

Comment: Thanks for the reply; I just tried using a physical connection and am getting the same problem (my bad). It seems VPN is not the problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved the problem.**

It turned out I had an entry in /etc/hosts that made my DC hostname resolve to a different IP address than the primary reverse resolver.

IE:

```
192.168.1.160 server
```

While `192.168.1.160` did not resolve back to this host.

I edited the hosts entry to reflect the correct IP-adress, which solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I whould also put the `domain=name` in the `options -o`